# How to find $\beta$

Tags: probability, convex-optimization, cumulative-distribution-functions

so my problem is I have to maximize $\bar{p}^Tx$,subject to  $\phi(\frac{\alpha - \bar{p}^Tx}{\sqrt{x^{T}\Sigma x}})\leq \beta$, where $\phi()$ is cumulative distribution function. I have to find $\beta$ such that the task is linear/convex/not convex. Can you please help me finding such $\beta$s?
This is the optimization:
$max \ \bar{p}^Tx$
$1^T x=1$
$\phi(\frac{\alpha - \bar{p}^Tx}{\sqrt{x^{T}\Sigma x}})\leq \beta$
Thanks for any help

Edit:
so $p \ \sim N(\bar{p},\Sigma)$, then $\bar{r}=\bar{p}^Tx$, then $\sigma^2=x^T \Sigma x$ and $r \sim N(\bar{r},\sigma^2)$ 
the maximization is 
$max \ \bar{p}^Tx$
$1^Tx=1$
$x^T \Sigma x \leq \sigma^2$
the alternative task is
$max \ \bar{p}^Tx$
$1^Tx=1$
$P(r\leq \alpha)\leq \beta$
where $\alpha$ is known and $\beta$ is maximal probability.
the constraint $P(r\leq \alpha)\leq \beta$ is equivalent to $P(\frac{r-\bar{r}}{\sigma}\leq \frac{\alpha-\bar{r}}{\sigma}) \leq \beta$, while $\frac{r-\bar{r}}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$. Now we can use cumulative distribution function: $P(\frac{r-\bar{r}}{\sigma}\leq \frac{\alpha-\bar{r}}{\sigma}) = \Phi(\frac{\alpha - \bar{r}}{\sigma})$.
Alright so this above is my assignment and now my job is to find for what $\beta$ is this task linear/convex/non convex. I also had to adjust my $\Phi(\frac{\alpha - \bar{r}}{\sigma})$ to $\Phi(\frac{\alpha - \bar{p}^Tx}{\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}})$. I hope now i gave you informations.

Comment: Is $\phi$ the cumulative *normal* distribution function?  Might make sense to give the context of how this problem arises, as that can sometime open up other avenues to solve, especially if there are probabilities involved.

Comment: @TickaJules I edited the question, hope i gave all necessary info

Comment: Sounds related to this:  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/portfolio-optimisation-with-var-or-cvar-constraints-using-linear-programming

Answer (score 1):

Consider the inequality $$\Phi\bigg(\frac{\alpha - \bar{p}^Tx}{\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}}\bigg)\leq \beta \iff \frac{\alpha - \bar{p}^Tx}{\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}} \leq \Phi^{-1}(\beta)$$
The above inequality can be equivalently written as
$$ \alpha - \Phi^{-1}(\beta)\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}-\bar{p}^Tx \leq 0$$
As $\Phi^{-1}(\beta)\leq 0$ for $\beta<0.5$ (see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function), thus, the term $- \Phi^{-1}(\beta)\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}$ is convex. Also, the term $\alpha-\bar{p}^Tx$ is convex. 
The sum of convex functions is convex, therefore, the problem becomes convex for $\beta<0.5$. 
I think the problem can never become linear because of the norm term.